# Restoring only some key values using COPY STDIN in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I accidentally ran a query on live data that deleted 5000 odd rows. I made a backup before I did this, and the backup is in this format:

```
COPY table (id, "position", event) FROM stdin;
529 1   5283
648 1   6473
687 1   6853
\.
```

Problem is, if I run it, i get:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table_pkey"
```

is there a way to alter this query to only insert the rows I deleted? Something like an "if exists, ignore" kind of thing? Normally I know this affects many things, but because it's literally just those entries that need to be replaced, I think something like this could work, but I don't know if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way may be to create a copy of the original table and restore to that.
Then insert to original table from copy where no entry exists in original.
e.g.

```
create table copy_table as select * from table where 1=2;
-- change the copy statement
COPY copy_table from stdin;
...

-- Insert to original
INSERT INTO table t1
SELECT ct.*
  FROM copy_table ct
       LEFT JOIN  table t2 ON t2.id = ct.id -- assuming id is primary key
 WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Using `create table copy_table like original_table` might be a better choice instead of the `as select...` if e.g. default values, not null or check constraints should be preserved.

Comment: Arguably unnecessary if this is just a quick and temporary table for restore process and the backup copy is considered reliable. In fact using unlogged table might serve.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is unfortunately not possible using the `COPY` command.

You need to insert all rows into a staging table, then use `insert into .. select ... where not exits (...)` to copy the misssing rows from the staging table into the real table.